# Как залить движок Magento?

Tags: magento

Помогите, пожалуйста, неопытному, начинающему программисту... Я хочу написать сайт интернет-магазин, создала свой виртуальный хостинг и не могу на него залить движок Magento. В чем проблема сама не знаю, оно просто не обновляет страницу и не пишет ошибку.

Comment: Как пытались? Что делали? Что подразумеваете под> ...свой виртуальный хостинг...и что под > не могу на него залить...  ???Операционка какая? Подробности в студию, плиззззUP ... в метках только phpmyadmin, еще что-нибудь есть?;)

Comment: нет, начинать надо с малого, с phpmyadmin :)

Comment: Сергей,а как с вами связаться ?

Comment: На самом деле в личке вопросы будут те же... Так что ЕЩЕ лучше - здесь. Только подумайте: будет же еще какой начинающий пользователь с похожим вопросом, начнет все с начала... а так !!!БАЦ!!! - вот вопрос, вот варианты ответов)))

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте все ли требования скрипта к серверу соблюдены.
Включите отображение ошибок. скорее всего оно поумолчанию на хостинге выключено.
Посмотрите логи php.
Если ничего не понятно -- обращайтесь в тех поддержку.

Comment: Как проверить, удовлетворяет ли сервер требованиям Magento:http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/how-do-i-know-if-my-server-is-compatible-with-magento

Comment: спасибо за ссылку.

Answer (score 2):

Могу сказать на примере IPBoard.
Наигравшись на локали, подключаюсь через ssh к хосту, копирую форум со всеми приложениями, копирую бэкап базы и там ее разворачиваю (поднимаю из бэкапа). И все - все внесенные изменения уже на хосте и доступны пользователям.
Думаю, в Вашем случае примерно так же.
Но это толко в случае, если все необходимые серверы подняты и работают (MySQL, Apache, nginx и т.п. что Вам необходимо).
А вообще, лучше уточнить по мануалу.

Comment: Честно говоря, по > создала свой виртуальный хостинг...мне показалось, что это в локали...)

Comment: да вообще сам пост и его начало уже многообещающее))

Comment: Ну, ежели "начинающий программист" хочет НАПИСАТЬ интернет-магазин - чтож, такое можно только поприветствовать... ИМХО, есть достаточное количество готовых решений - как проприетарных, так и [OpenSource][1]. Я вот уже пол-года в восторге от [Drupal][2]  [1]: http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%82%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5  [2]: http://drupal.org

Comment: неопытный... начинающий... может чего-нить по проще? на хэшкоде таких амбициозных последнее время... :)

Comment: Да пусть себе растут люди...)))

Comment: к тому же начинающий программист врядли знает достаточно хорошо пхп чтобы работать с магентой)

Comment: Конечно, пусть растут - все мы тоже когда-то с чего-то начинали.  И не стоит так г-ну @thunder `у вредничать - сам же был начинающим, и, возможно, не менее амбициозным :) До сих пор сам учусь, у спрашиваю на профильных форумах или в конференциях

Comment: не покушался на инетмагазины уж точно) гостевые книжки -- даа, простенький ломающийся сайтик -- даа)))

Comment: Ну я дальше не шиб-ко то ушел - более админ, чем программер, хотя морды на VB под базы писал...